# How to append a string to a value in a table in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to append a String to a value in a table something like
Before Query value = 451,654
After Executing Query It Should Be = 451,654,456

```
UPDATE `orders` SET `instalments`= ??? WHERE `order_id`= 24
```

What Should I Replace The Questions Marks '???' with In The Above Query To Achieve The Desired Result?

Comment: What is the data type of instalments and what is the purpose of the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the column are string you should use concat

```
UPDATE orders 
SET instalments = concat(instalments , ',456')
WHERE order_id = 24
```